# How to get all the contents with foreach loop except for those having some class in simple html dom.php

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

Suppose i have a code like this:

```
 <div class="container">
        <span class="toshow">item1</span>
        <span class="toshow">item2</span>
        <span class="toshow">item3</span>
        <span class="show">item4</span>
        <span class="notshow">item4</span>
        <span class="notshow">item5</span>
        <span class="another">item5</span>
        <span class="another">item5</span>
    </div>
```

Now i just want to show the items having class "toshow" excluding the "notshow" items:

```
<?php
foreach($html->find('div[class="container"]') as $element)
echo $elemtnt->plaintext.'<br>';
?>
```

Also, i have tried this to exclude the span having class  "notshow"  :

```
<?php
foreach($html->find('div[class="container"] span[class! = "notshow"]') as $element)
echo $elemtnt->plaintext.'<br>';
?>
```

How to show all items using foreach loop?
[simple_html_dom.php](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find all spans with class "toshow" you could use `div[class="container"] span[class="toshow"]`

For example

```
foreach($html->find('div[class="container"] span[class=toshow]') as $element) {
    echo $element->plaintext . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
item1
item2
item3
```

Or show all spans where the class not is `notshow`

```
foreach($html->find('div[class="container"] span[class!=notshow]') as $element) {
    echo $element->plaintext . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
item1
item2
item3
item4
item5
item5
```

Comment: I have tried this but `hasclass` is not working . It shows "unknown property or method".

Comment: @DivyanshuSah I used the latest version `1.9.1` Which version are you using?

Comment: I don't know i just downloaded it from [https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/]here.

Comment: @ the fourth bird. i don't know why but it shows the `hasclass` is unknown property or method. ;)

Comment: @DivyanshuSah We use the same version, and  The hasClass is present in the code.  See this link for the code that I use to test it https://ideone.com/l9wsO0 (note that this link is only to share the code, it does not work by itself)

Comment: @DivyanshuSah Did it work out eventually?

Comment: No, I just want to exclude that items  having class "notshow" and "another".
 By using this i get all the plaintext value `$main_div = $html->find('div[class="container"]')->plaintext;` but i want to exclude the spans having class "notshow" and "another".
How to exclude that ?

Comment: I think this `span[class!=notshow]` is not working. with this `span[class!=notshow] ` i am only getting the value of "notshow" but i want to exclue them. So i tried like this 
`span:not(.notshow)` but it also doesn't work. do you have any other idea?

Comment: @DivyanshuSah I pasted the whole simple html dom file in this demo with `span[class!=notshow]` See https://ideone.com/qHwxCq See the output at the bottom

Comment: I added a new "span" with `class="parent"` now look how code is like:
https://ideone.com/0yzfMl  .  it is repeatiting why?. i have to exclude the `not-show`

Comment: see at the bottom.at top of `stdout`. it is repeatiting two times .
at first they printed all. then it print with excluding `"notshow"`

Comment: @DivyanshuSah I think you pasted the code 2 times, but you get that output because `<span class="parent">` is also a span where the selector matches and has no class notshow.

Comment: so it means that i have to also include `<span class="parent">`? 

can't i do this simply without including `<span class="parent">` in selecter?
like it is very difficult to include "parent". isn't any simple option to do this?

Comment: @DivyanshuSah You can just add the span with parent like `foreach($html->find('div[class="container"] span.parent span[class!=notshow]') as $element) {`

Comment: sure i don't need reputation but i will upvote you.

Answer (score 1):

if you use DOMXpath you can do something like:

```
    $xdoc = new DomDocument;
$xdoc->loadHTMLFile("xxxx");
$xpath = new DOMXpath($xdoc);
$xpath->query(".//*[contains(@class,'toshow')]");
```

or for notshow

```
$xpath->query(".//*[not(contains(@class,'notshow'))]");
```